# I want to use (sort insert) in letters, not numbers, but I didn't understand how

Tags: c++

I want to use (sort insert) in letters, not numbers, but I didn't understand how
I wrote this code using the (Insertion sort array).

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, key, j;  
    for (i = 1; n - 1; i++) 
    {  
        key = arr[i];  
        j = i - 1;  

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) 
        {  
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];  
            j = j - 1;  
        }  
        arr[j + 1] = key;  
    }  
}  


void printArray(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i;  
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    cout << endl; 
}
```

***But there is an error here***

```
    int main()  
{  
    char s[] = { "Q, R, Y, M, N, L, O" };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    insertionSort(arr, n);  
    printArray(arr, n);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: "But there is an error here" - what's the error?

Comment: What is your error? Keep in mind that the `char s[]` contains 20 characters: `'Q', ',', ' ', 'R', ',', ' ', ..., 'O', '\0'`. You're also trying to take the `sizeof(arr)`, when `arr` isn't declared. What's the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: We're also aware that you didn't write this original code. It's fine. Taking pieces of other people's code is okay and we won't crucify you for it. But you can be honest here about that.

Comment: Your `insertionSort` doesn't work, and your `main` doesn't compile. You must work on simpler exercises a while longer, until you master the basics.

Comment: If your compiler is up to date you'll have access to `std::size`, and that sucker can get you the size of pretty much anything that still has a known size.

Comment: How did you know that I didn't write it? I study this in a textbook

Comment: Any textbook that starts code samples with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` should be burned and its ashes buried on consecrated ground.

Comment: any textbook that uses this prototype should be burned: `void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)  `

Comment: I learned (Insertion sort array)  from the book but  #include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std; learned it myself

Comment: Do anyone help me or not?

Comment: Praise Crom. I recommend you unlearn it. anything inside the bits folder is implementation specific for the g++ compiler and not intended for direct inclusion. Weird things can and do happen. In this case there is little weird, but it includes the entire C++ standard library and that's a lot of extra work for the compiler and tens of thousands of extra symbols running loose inside your program you now have to avoid.

Comment: Additional reading on the topic: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Ok, Is all code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did small fixes in your code

```
void insertionSort(char arr[], int n) // coz you pass the array of char
```

and

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) // coz loop should be till the end. not n - 1 condition
```

and

```
void printArray(char arr[], int n) // coz u pass array of char type
```

and finally

```
int main()  
{  
    char s[] = { 'Q', 'R', 'Y', 'M', 'N', 'L', 'O' }; // read about initializin arrays and designated initializers if u need it
    int n = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]); // arr replaced with s

    insertionSort(s, n);  // arr replaced with s
    printArray(s, n);   // arr replaced with s

    return 0;  
}
```

As people mentioned here you should start from the basics first. Try to avoid copy people's code until u understand what happens while execution of this code.

Insertion sort [more details](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110793/insertion-sort-in-c/110827)

Answer (score 0):

Your character array is named `s`, but you tried to calculate its length assuming the name of the array is `arr`

Fix the array name:

```
int main()  
{  
    char arr[] = { "Q, R, Y, M, N, L, O" };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    insertionSort(arr, n);  
    printArray(arr, n);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: @HussamTaha Make sure the error is the same error. You're going to find that it's easy to have multiple errors and for one error to conceal others. Compilers have gotten better, but when I was learning fixing one error often lead to the revelation of hundreds more because the compiler could now process further.